# Python mypy type error with Union of callable and list of callable converted to list of callable

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

The argument `hook` can either be a function or a list of function. If it's a function, I convert it to a list so I can assume it's a list later.

```py
HookType = Union[Callable[[str], str], List[Callable[[str], str]]]

...

def __init__(
    ...
    hook: HookType = [],
):
    ...
    if type(hook) is not list:
        hook = [hook]
    self.hook: List[Callable[[str], str]] = hook
```

When I run `mypy` I get the following error:

```
foo.py:54: error: List item 0 has incompatible type "Union[Callable[[str], str], List[Callable[[str], str]]]"; expected "Callable[[str], str]"
foo.py:57: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Union[Callable[[str], str], List[Callable[[str], str]]]", variable has type "List[Callable[[str], str]]")
Found 4 errors in 1 file (checked 20 source files)
```

Doesn't `mypy` detect the condition which checks the type of `hook`?

I should also mention that I enabled a few mypy options:

```
[mypy]
check_untyped_defs = true
disallow_incomplete_defs = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be "fixed" by using `isinstance` instead (at least in Pycharm's implementation of the static checker):

```
if not isinstance(hook, list):
    hook = [hook]
```

MyPy is stricter than Pycharm, but I'd expect it to fix it for MyPy as well. `if type(x) is y` seems to throw type checkers.